# Change nameString using arcpy?

Tags: arcpy, python, layers, arcgis-10.5

Is it possible to change the describe `nameString` of a `.lyr` file using `arcpy`? The name of the `.lyr` file is correct, but when the `.lyr` is brought into an `.mxd` the display name (`nameString`) is different, and I would like to make them the same.

I'm looking to remove "`_clip`" from `.lyr`s that have it in their `nameString`:

```
import arcpy
import os

workspace = r"C:\..."
lyrs = []

walk = arcpy.da.Walk(workspace)

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:
    for filename in filenames:
        lyrs.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))

for lyr in lyrs:
    desc = arcpy.Describe(lyr)

    if "_clip" in desc.nameString[-5:]:
        print desc.nameString
```

nameStrings are read only - https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/layer-properties.htm

Using ArcGIS Desktop 10.5

Comment: Can't you just edit the layer name when it's loaded in the map then save out a new layer file overwriting the old one, then you would not have to do any of this?

Comment: In my case, no. This is part of a larger tool being used in my organization, and that request wouldn't be reasonable.

Comment: With your new amended code, what is unsuccessful about it? You don't say if there is an error message or it runs doing some partial changes or a straight up nothing happens?

Comment: It completes successfully. When i then drag the layer into an .mxd it still has the original name.Nothing happens. I confirmed that the layers are going into the loop properly, and "lyr_in" is being assigned the layer.

Comment: Is `lyr` that is coming out of `lyrs` the layerfile so it should be something like `c:\temp\data\geology.lyr`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a [layer object](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/layer-class.htm) from your file path. You can update and save the layer file using layer object properties and methods.

```
>>> lyrFl = r"C:\test.lyr" 
>>> arcpy.Describe (lyrFl).nameString #check name with describe
u'mains'
>>> lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer (lyrFl) #create layer object
>>> lyr.name
u'mains'
>>> lyr.name = "newname" #change name
>>> lyr.save () #save layer
>>> lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer (lyrFl) #test to see if it worked
>>> lyr.name
u'newname'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to load the *layer file* into a map document, adjust the *layer* name and then overwrite the *layer file*. This could be achieved via the [layer object](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/layer-class.htm) via the mapping module.  Currently your code is trying to manipulate the layer file outside the map document and accessing a property which as you have discovered is read only.